# Using external include files in Flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, progress-4gl, openedge, flex4.6

How can I insert pieces of code into MXML that are included at compile time in the code, such as Progress includes ? For example : in Progress I use this way to do what I want.

MyInclude.i

```
DEF VAR myVar AS CHAR NO-UNDO.  
FUNCTION fnSetChar RETURNS LOGICAL:  
ASSIGN myVar = 'test'.  
END FUNCTION.
```

MyProgram.p

```
{MyInclude.i}
MESSAGE fnSetChar() SKIP myVar
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX BUTTONS OK.
```

There is many ways to use includes in Progress, passing parameters, reusing codes, etc.

I would like to know if anyone have an idea how can I do something like this in Flex. i.e.:

```
<fx:Declarations>
//include the content of the "include file" here in compile time
</fx:Declarations>
```

Sorry for my English. Hope anyone can help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused, what do you want to do with said code.  With the information you have given me, I think you either want to use the <fx:Script> tag and keep your script there, or use embedded objects if you want to store things such as images and sometimes externalized text..

Comment: Yes ... It's a little confuse. I'll try to be more specific. I'm using Flex 4.6 to develop a front-end to an application that resides in a server powered by Progress software through a "web-server" that behaves like "Webspeed" (Webspeed is from Progress Software too). To do the communication (this is made by XML exchange) is intended to use HTTPServices on Flex side. Inside `<fx:Declarations>` I have a lot of `<s:HTTPService>` calls (more than 20) because of the structure I'm using in the Progress backend. What I want is to spare the `<s:HTTPService>` calls into separate text files [...]

Comment: [...] and reference this files inside the `<fx:Declarations>` to make the code visually more "clean". What I tried to say is that in Progress we have a concept called "includes", which behaves exactly as I want : the code resides in a separated file ("include" file) and just referenced in the main code (as shown in MyProgram.p example above). At compile time the compiler incorporates its contents and manage them as if they were wrote in main program. For instance : in "MyProgram.p" the compiler overlays {MyInclude.i} with the code inside the file "MyInclude.i" [...]

Comment: [...] which makes "MyProgram.p" looks like this to the compiler : `DEF VAR myVar AS CHAR NO-UNDO.  
FUNCTION fnSetChar RETURNS LOGICAL:  
ASSIGN myVar = 'test'.  
END FUNCTION.
MESSAGE fnSetChar() SKIP myVar
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX BUTTONS OK.`
I don't know if I achieved the level of details I want to show but I hope that time it was more clear than before.

Comment: In your example, would you want the <fx:Declarations> tag to contain the output `test` or the code `DEF VAR myVar AS CHAR NO-UNDO.  
FUNCTION fnSetChar RETURNS LOGICAL:  
ASSIGN myVar = 'test'.
END FUNCTION.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [How would I include an MXML file inline another MXML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819474/how-would-i-include-an-mxml-file-inline-another-mxml-file), there's no way to do *exactly* what you're asking.  However, you can easily rewrite your `<s:HTTPService>` objects using Actionscript instead of MXML.

So you'll go from this in MyFlex.mxml:

```
<s:Application ...>
  <fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="service1" url="http://www.example.com/s1/" />
    <s:HTTPService id="service2" url="http://www.example.com/s2/" />
    <s:HTTPService id="service3" url="http://www.example.com/s3/" />
  </fx:Declarations>

  <s:Group id="visualContainer">
    <!-- other visible controls here -->
    <s:Button label="Service one" click="service1.send()" />
  </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

to the following:

```
<s:Application ...>
  <fx:Script source="includes/IncludedFile.as"/>

  <s:Group id="visualContainer">
    <!-- visible controls here -->
    <s:Button label="Service one" click="service1.send()" />
  </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

includes/IncludedFile.as:

```
var service1:HTTPService = new HTTPService("http://www.example.com/s1/");
var service2:HTTPService = new HTTPService("http://www.example.com/s1/");
var service3:HTTPService = new HTTPService("http://www.example.com/s1/");
```

See also [Including versus importing ActionScript code](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7ff4.html) for more info on this topic.